# Set blurred background via swift in tvOS

Tags: frameworks, tvos

I have a simple tvOS app in swift, where I want to change the background to a different image on specific screens. Apples hig for tvOS has some screenshots where this apparently was done ([p.e. the screenshot under "Tables and Collections"](https://developer.apple.com/tvos/human-interface-guidelines/ui-elements/))

Is there an API to do this? I couldn't find one, but I've seen this done in a few apps. As a workaround I could probably insert a fullscreen image with a UIVisualEffectView above it, to achieve something similar, but that seems wrong.

Comment: I'm not aware of any API that will do this for you automatically. I'd assume they are using a `UIVisualEffectView` as you mentioned.

Comment: As explained by Apple in WWDC 2014's [*Creating Custom iOS User Interfaces*][1], `UIVisualEffectView` is strongly optimized. I assume they are using the method you explained, since Apple uses the same controls we use for development and UIVisualEffectView is in the system since iOS 7 and is public and available for developers since iOS 8.  


  [1]: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/221/

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'll use that then. Just feels weird/wrong to put that on top of what appears to already be exactly the same thing. Maybe tvOS 10 will bring an API for it!